# What causes segmentation fault in this code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fault

My task was to load unknown number of integers from <0;99> and then print all  second digits which were among integers followed by first digits of the number where the second digits occurred. For example:

For numbers:

```
1 2 5 2 25 27 93 4 93 93 58 51
```

I should get this output:

```
0 | 12245
2 | 57
5 | 18
9 | 333
```

I think the mistake is somewhere here:

```
digit_holder[number/10] = (int *) realloc(digit_holder[number/10],(realloc_count[(number/10)]*sizeof(int)));
digit_holder[number/10][realloc_count[number/10]-1] = number % 10;
```

Full code:

```
int main()
{
  int i,j, number,realloc_count[10], *digit_holder[10];
  for (i = 0; i<10;i++)
    realloc_count[i] = 0;
  while (scanf("%d",&number) > 0){
    realloc_count[number/10]++;
    digit_holder[number/10] = (int *) realloc(digit_holder[number/10],(realloc_count[(number/10)]*sizeof(int)));
    digit_holder[number/10][realloc_count[number/10]-1] = number % 10;
  }
  for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%d | ",i);
    for (j = 0; j < realloc_count[j]; j++)
  printf("%d",digit_holder[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
  }



  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`realloc()` first parameter is either a pointer perviously returned by malloc or realloc, or NULL. You need to initialize your `digit_holder` array entries to NULL.